# Java + Android -> Null pointer exception while starting new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, rx-java

when I return from my game activity to main activity I get a NPE. In a function, which isn't even called. (when i tried to write in console before that line, it does nothing)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.semanticer.unstable.presentation.GameView.showGameBoard(com.example.semanticer.unstable.domain.model.GameBoard)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.semanticer.unstable.presentation.GamePresenter.lambda$onCreate$0(GamePresenter.java:23)
```

this is where i want to return to main activity - yes i tried finish() too.

```
@Override
public void playAgain(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

this is the line i get error on

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    game = GameImpl.createNew(6, 4);
    **view().subscribe(view -> view.showGameBoard(game.getBoard()));**
    view().subscribe(view -> view.showCurrentPlayer(Player.FIRST_PLAYER));
    view().subscribe(view -> view.showScore(Player.FIRST_PLAYER, Player.SECOND_PLAYER, game));
    view().subscribe(view -> view.hideWinnerText());
}
```

whole project is on github -> https://github.com/zdenduk/AndroidUnstableAtoms

you can find layouts here -

> /zdenduk/AndroidUnstableAtoms/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout

and source code here ->

> /zdenduk/AndroidUnstableAtoms/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/semanticer/unstable

Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: I really wouldn't suggest using lambdas-  Java 8 support is still in the experimental stage.  It also greatly reduces the support you can get here-  almost nobody on the android tag uses it.  Beyond that-  what the heck is view()?  Its not part of Android and you haven't provided it for us.  But your problem is certain to come down to an uninitialized variable somewhere.

Comment: Method view() can be found here: https://github.com/konmik/nucleus/blob/249ab08547cb2b10ddce268dfb0b27b5013623c2/nucleus/src/main/java/nucleus/presenter/RxPresenter.java

Comment: I'm going to say this and I mean to be constructive not critical-  your code is unreadable.  There's zero utility in making code this abstract and to abuse RxJava here.  It would take a day or two to understand enough of what's going on here to debug it.  All you're trying to do is show a gameboard.  Do that.  What you have is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @GabeSechan  I'm using lambdas from retrolambda on production for at least a year and everything is fine (and everybody I know is using it as well). I cannot even imagine working with complex rxjava chains w/o lambdas and method references.

Comment: @Than I'd be avoiding the complex RxJava chains to. RxJava has a place , but it makes your code much less debuggable. In this case we'd be talking about a few dozen easily read and understood lines of code, vs multiple libraries and a bug where none could tell him easily what his actual problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
com.example.semanticer.unstable.presentation.GameView.showGameBoard(com.example.semanticer.unstable.domain.model.GameBoard)' on a null object reference
```

says that showGameBoard is thrown on a null object reference, i.e. the reference called "view" seems to be null.

You can find the *view* variable that is inherited here:
https://github.com/konmik/nucleus/blob/249ab08547cb2b10ddce268dfb0b27b5013623c2/nucleus/src/main/java/nucleus/presenter/Presenter.java

So this might probably help you:

```
 /**
     * Returns a current view attached to the presenter or null.
     *
     * View is normally available between
     * {@link Activity#onResume()} and {@link Activity#onPause()},
     * {@link Fragment#onResume()} and {@link Fragment#onPause()},
     * {@link android.view.View#onAttachedToWindow()} and {@link android.view.View#onDetachedFromWindow()}.
     *
     * Calls outside of these ranges will return null.
     * Notice here that {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} is called *before* {@link Activity#onResume()}
     * so you can't use this method as a callback.
     *
     * @return a current attached view.
     */
    @Nullable
    public View getView() {
        return view;
}
```

Presenter.java is the base class.

Comment: Great :) Don't forget to accept this answer if it proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException like this genrally is the the result of an undefined variable.

If I had to guess from your code (looks like I would need some more of it to accurately help) I would say

```
game = GameImpl.createNew(6, 4);
```

needs to be defined or isn't properly defined. Try looking there first then go from there. Good luck! :)

Comment: it's on git, under presentation folder :) thanks anyway

Comment: The error says ON a null object reference. showGameBoard(), however, is never called on the reference called "game", therefore the error above cannot be caused by this line.

Comment: If game WAS null, an error would be thrown regarding the getBoard() method (called on "game"), not regarding the showGameBoard() method, which is called on the view reference.

Comment: View reference makes sense now that I've taken a second look. Perhaps when I get home I will try to find the git project on the Computer.